# why "jitsu deploy" got "Error: Cannot find module 'browserid-verifier'"?

Tags: node.js, npm, nodejitsu

Seems only a module's missing, but I've wrote the in the `package.json`file, and others seems fine.
I've debugged this little app locally many times, there is a version of browserid module here...
The `browserid-verifier` module can be found here:
https://github.com/lloyd/node-browserid
and, `package.jsonq file:

```
{
  "name": "daily_bookmarks",
  "subdomain": "daily_bookmarks",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "server.coffee"
  },
  "version": "0.0.0-9",
  "engines": {
    "node": "0.6.x"
  },
  "main": "server.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "mongodb": "0.9.9",
    "socket.io": "0.9.3",
    "ezcrypto": "0.0.3",
    "browserid-verifier": "0.0.4"
  }
}
```

the version on my laptop:

```
$ npm list -g | grep browser
├─┬ browserid-verifier@0.0.4 
│   ├─┬ browserify@1.8.1
```

ERROR:

```
$ jitsu deploy
info:   Welcome to Nodejitsu
info:   It worked if it ends with Nodejitsu ok
info:   Executing command deploy
info:   Analyzing your application dependencies in server.coffee
warn:   Local version appears to be old.
warn:   Your package.json version will be incremented for you automatically.
warn:   About to write /home/chen/code/home/git/docview/projects/daily_bookmarks/package.json
data:   
data:   {
data:       engines: { node: '0.6.x' },
data:       dependencies: {
data:           socket.io: '0.9.3',
data:           browserid-verifier: '0.0.4',
data:           mongodb: '0.9.9',
data:           ezcrypto: '0.0.3'
data:       },
data:       subdomain: 'daily_bookmarks',
data:       version: '0.0.0-9',
data:       name: 'daily_bookmarks',
data:       main: 'server.js',
data:       scripts: { start: 'server.coffee' }
data:   }
data:   
prompt: Is this ok? (yes): 
warn:   Creating new snapshot for version 0.0.0-9
info:   Done creating snapshot 0.0.0-9
info:   Updating application daily_bookmarks
info:   Activating snapshot 0.0.0-9 for daily_bookmarks
info:   Stopping app daily_bookmarks
info:   App daily_bookmarks is now stopped
info:   Starting app daily_bookmarks
error:  Error running command deploy
error:  Nodejitsu Error (500): Internal Server Error
info:   Nodejitsu not ok
```

Comment: If you haven't already update the jitsu client (it's the first thing you'll be asked to do from support). Usually find the second attempt to deploy fixes the problem (this is a well known, but tricky bug to catch). 

If this doesn't fix the problem, then would I recommend you gist the jitsulog, ping the guys with the gist url on either irc (#nodejitsu) or twitter (@nodejitsu).

Comment: I installed jitsu at the same day as that happened, it should be the latest version. Later I tried to push to Heroku, even NAE(another Node app engine).. failed again and again.. Probably something wrong with the package..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
npm ERR! error installing jwcrypto@0.1.1
npm ERR! error installing browserid-verifier@0.0.4

npm ERR! ...SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:s23_clnt.c:683:
```

This is what I got while I was trying to install *browserid-verifier* locally. It seems that there is some problem while trying to *npm install* it. You can bundle it in your app.

```
"bundleDependencies": [
  "browserid-verifier"
]
```

Comment: http://npmjs.org/doc/json.html  I've checked docs, but I'm still not clear about what's the difference about `bundleDependencies` and `dependencies`? And on my laptop, `browserid-verifier` was installed  succcesfully. That's confusing.

Comment: `depencencies` are pulled from npm like normal, whereas `bundledDependencies` are bundled with your package. This allows you to have custom versions of modules inside your `node_modules` folder without having to pull them from an outside source.